# Elasticsearch mapping: How to analyze or map to numeric fields?

Tags: elasticsearch, mapping, elasticsearch-analyzers

I want to index the `month` field of a bibtex entry into elasticsearch and make it searchable via the `range` query. This requires the underlying field type to be some kind of numeric datatype. In my case `short` would be sufficient.

The bibtex `month` field in its canonical form requires a three character abbreviation, so I tried to use the `char_filter` like so:

```
...
"char_filter": {
    "month_char_filter": {
        "type": "mapping",
        "mappings": [
            "jan => 1",
            "feb => 2",
            "mar => 3",
            ...
            "nov => 11",
            "dec => 12"
        ]
    }
...
"normalizer": {
    "month_normalizer": {
        "type": "custom",
        "char_filter": [ "month_char_filter" ],
    },
```

And put up mappings like this:

```
...
"month": {
    "type": "short",
    "normalizer": "month_normalizer"
},
...
```

But it doesn't seem to work since the `type` field doesn't support normalizers like this, as well as it doesn't support analyzers.

So what would be the approach to implement such a mapping as shown in the `char_filter` part so there are range query possibilites?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach intuitively makes sense, however, normalizers can only be applied to `keyword` fields and analyzers to `text` fields.

Another approach would be to leverage the [ingest processors](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ingest-processors.html) and use the [`script` processor](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/script-processor.html) to do that mapping at indexing time.

Below you can find a simulation of such a `script` processor that would create a new field called `monthNum` based on the month present in the `month` field.

```
POST _ingest/pipeline/_simulate
{
  "pipeline": {
    "processors": [
      {
        "script": {
          "source": """
          def mapping = ['jan', 'feb', 'mar', 'apr', 'may', 'jun', 'jul', 'aug', 'sep', 'oct', 'nov', 'dec'];
          ctx.monthNum = mapping.indexOf(ctx.month) + 1;
          """
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "docs": [
    {
      "_source": {
        "month": "feb"
      }
    },
    {
      "_source": {
        "month": "mar"
      }
    },
    {
      "_source": {
        "month": "jul"
      }
    },
    {
      "_source": {
        "month": "aug"
      }
    },
    {
      "_source": {
        "month": "nov"
      }
    },
    {
      "_source": {
        "month": "dec"
      }
    },
    {
      "_source": {
        "month": "xyz"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Resulting documents:

```
{
  "docs" : [
    {
      "doc" : {
        "_index" : "_index",
        "_type" : "_type",
        "_id" : "_id",
        "_source" : {
          "monthNum" : 2,
          "month" : "feb"
        },
        "_ingest" : {
          "timestamp" : "2019-05-08T12:28:27.006Z"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "doc" : {
        "_index" : "_index",
        "_type" : "_type",
        "_id" : "_id",
        "_source" : {
          "monthNum" : 3,
          "month" : "mar"
        },
        "_ingest" : {
          "timestamp" : "2019-05-08T12:28:27.006Z"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "doc" : {
        "_index" : "_index",
        "_type" : "_type",
        "_id" : "_id",
        "_source" : {
          "monthNum" : 7,
          "month" : "jul"
        },
        "_ingest" : {
          "timestamp" : "2019-05-08T12:28:27.006Z"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "doc" : {
        "_index" : "_index",
        "_type" : "_type",
        "_id" : "_id",
        "_source" : {
          "monthNum" : 8,
          "month" : "aug"
        },
        "_ingest" : {
          "timestamp" : "2019-05-08T12:28:27.006Z"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "doc" : {
        "_index" : "_index",
        "_type" : "_type",
        "_id" : "_id",
        "_source" : {
          "monthNum" : 11,
          "month" : "nov"
        },
        "_ingest" : {
          "timestamp" : "2019-05-08T12:28:27.006Z"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "doc" : {
        "_index" : "_index",
        "_type" : "_type",
        "_id" : "_id",
        "_source" : {
          "monthNum" : 12,
          "month" : "dec"
        },
        "_ingest" : {
          "timestamp" : "2019-05-08T12:28:27.006Z"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "doc" : {
        "_index" : "_index",
        "_type" : "_type",
        "_id" : "_id",
        "_source" : {
          "monthNum" : 0,
          "month" : "xyz"
        },
        "_ingest" : {
          "timestamp" : "2019-05-08T12:28:27.006Z"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you, those are two completely new aspects to me, I'll dig into it right away ! :) I think scripting is the way to go anyway, because i can't even guarantee that every `month` entry follows the three character guidelines.